# Search entire table using pipe angular

Tags: angular, angular6, pipe

How to search a value from the entire table which is paginated. Currently, i am only getting the search value from page 1 if it is selected and likewise.What i need is to search the value from entire table whichever page is selected.

Here is my code

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Search..">
 <table  class="table table-striped table-hover" [mfData]="pendingReports" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="10" >
 <thead>
 <tr>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let data of mf.data | grdFilter: { ireportid: searchText,Property:searchText}">
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5,10,25]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
```

Filter Pipe:

```
export class GrdFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any, filter: any, defaultFilter: boolean): any {
    if (!filter){
      return items;
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(items)){
      return items;
    }

    if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
      let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);

      if (defaultFilter) {
        return items.filter(item =>
            filterKeys.reduce((x, keyName) =>
                (x && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] == "", true));
      }
      else {
        return items.filter(item => {
          return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
            return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName] == "";
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is most likely not going to be possible, because if you're using pagination that means that your UI only has a part of the data you're trying to filter. And can therefore only provide you a **partial** result.

You would need to implement a filter function on your server to achieve what you want, because your server has a "global" view of the data.